# How to change and manipulate the data inside a cell ng-grid with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid from AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.myData = gridData;
        $scope.gridOptions = {
                        data: 'myData',
                        columnDefs: ColumnArray
                        };
    });
```

I want to change a cell text inside a cell. How to do that? 
I was using cellTemplate:

```
ColumnObject.cellTemplate = GetCellTemplate();
```

But, *my GetCellTemplate* method can not read **{{ row.getProperty(col.field) }}** which is the data in the current cell. What to do in order to be able to read the cell data/text and change it in run time.

For example, if my cell has text like "My Name IMAGE" I want to be able to change the word "IMAGE" into a real image and display it in my ng-grid.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: try reading like this  row.entity.{property name}

Answer (score 1):

You can use an angular directive in the cellTemplate.

For example:

```
.directive('replacewithimage', function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'C',
                replace: true,
                transclude: true,
                scope: { colValue:'@colValue' },
                 template: '<div ng-switch="colValue">' +
                    '<div ng-switch-when="IMAGE"><img src="#"></div> '     +
                    '<div ng-switch-default>{{valor}}</div> '
                    +'</div>'
            }


    })
```

and then use it in the cellTemplate of the ng-grid passing the "class" name as "replacewithimage" and the value as the "colValue" attribute

```
> ..
  cellTemplate: '<div> class="replacewithimage"
> colValue="{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}"></div>'},
..
```

Answer (score 0):

@l2mt, I tried your example with following changes:

```
template: '<div ng-switch="colValue">' +
            ' <div ng-switch-when="1">Valid Data</div>' +
            '<div ng-switch-when="2">Invalid Data</div>' +
            '<div ng-switch-default>NONE</div>' +
          '</div>
```

There are 2 row in a ng-grid column with values 1 and 2.

cellTemplate has the same code as yours. But it displays NONE for both the rows not "Valid Data" or "Invalid Data".